# Merging excel documents similar to slide libraries

Tags: 2010, excel, office-integration

I have a scenario that would be perfect for slide libraries - but they're excel sheets.  We use SharePoint 2010.  Also, I do not have access to the server itself... Just site collection administrator.

Currently, I have six organizations which all submit an excel document via e-mail.  I then take the excel document that they submit me, and paste it over an existing sheet in a master excel document (one tab per organization).  Then I upload this master document onto SharePoint.

Ideally, I would like one document per organization on SharePoint, that they update.  Then, through some automated process, the user could download a document with one tab per organization.

Hopefully it would work just like slide libraries...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm solving this problem by the following:

- document library with content approval, that the organizations can modify.
- Once a week (or so), I will manually download all of the excel documents
- Special .XLSM that pulls the first sheet out of all of those excel documents, puts it into current document, saves as a .XLS
- Manually upload the merged document

Answer (score 0):

You wont get that functionality without coding a solution via Excel Services. You could actually probably do this via the CSOM for Excel Services, but I imagine it would be pretty tedious.

Ideally you would convert the Excel sheet data points to a list and have them populated the data via listform or a customized InfoPath form.  From there you could export and link that data to Excel and format the worksheet for your reporting needs.

If you have PowerPivot plugin for Excel2010, you can use Excel workbooks as datasources, and bring all the workbooks into the data model, then build your master off that data there.  As workbooks are updated you can just refresh the master to pull in the new data.  This requires however that you keep the workbook names the same.  You could do this without PowerPivot, it is just an a pretty easy tool for working with different data sources in Excel.

Comment: Unfortunately, the network/computers/servers here are quite restricted.  Cannot code custom solutions.  Do not have extra plugins.